# Question about the proscribed use of “have” along with “get” or “be”

Tags: passive-voice, causative-verbs, get-be

I have asked before and been told that along with the usage of *have*, there shouldn't be any other words like *be* or *get*, as the *have* already conveys the meaning on its own.

**Example 1:**

- She never had it easy, always working with no breaks.
- She never had it **be** easy, always working with no breaks.

**Example 2:**

- I was running and had my laces get undone.
- I was running and had my laces **undo**.

In the second example, I think it would be correct to use *get* so that it conveys the sense that the laces **became** undone.

This is a sample sentence I found on the internet:

> You never have the guy be the one wrapping his legs around the girl. That’s just a no to life.

### *And my question is. . . .*

So is it acceptable to use the verbs *be* or *get* together with *have* when trying to tell about an experience which includes no intention of the speaker that anything should be done to them?

In other words, can you use these for a passive thing that they have no control over, the way there is a rule of ordering for something to be done attached to the most common usage of *have*?

Even though in the past every time I’ve asked I’ve been told that using *be* and *get* along with *have* is “incorrect”, I still hear people using such constructions.

Comment: Idiomatically, the general rule is we say things like *"I will have you flogged!"* rather than *"I will have you **be** flogged!"*, whereas if the verb isn't ***have***, we usually *do* include *to be* in one form or another (*"I want you **to be** flogged!"*). In your second example we'd normally expect ***become***, and in the third the continuous ***being*** might be a bit more "elegant".

Comment: Related and possible duplicate: [“I had my house ［be］ burned down”](http://english.stackexchange.com/q/177009/2085).

Comment: I'm afraid that whoever told you that is talking nonsense. Who in the world has the authority to say "There shouldn't be any verbs like _be_ or _get_"? The auxiliary _be_ and the verbs _get_ and _have_, which can also be auxiliary verbs, can occur in dozens of types of verb phrase constructions, some together and some not. Please feel free to pay no attention to grammar advice from anyone ignorant enough to tell you that. They don't know what they're talking about.

Comment: Idiomatically, we'd expect laces to have ***come* undone** rather than to have *become* undone, even if *become* would work for most other hands-off state changes that would require a reflexive formulation in other European languages. English grammar is mostly simple, except where it is fractally complex, and the hard parts are more likely to be found in homely usage than in carefully crafted formal writing. (That usage of *homely* is somewhat archaic, by the way, but there is no good modern substitute.)

Comment: But, overall is it still okay to use be and get with have? Like:

Comment: Thank you, so overall is it okay to use be/get along with have? Like: Can we not have books getting/being thrown around in the classroom? or should it be Can we not have book thrown around in the classroom.

Comment: @John Lawler Thank you, so overall is it okay to use be/get along with have? Like: Can we not have books getting/being thrown around in the classroom? or should it be Can we not have books thrown around in the classroom.

Comment: @user79773: **If** you use the correct form of the verb, amd **if** you do so in the correct construction, yes. Otherwise, no.

Comment: @John Lawler could you provide some examples for clarification please?

Comment: You're asking for several thousand examples. This is very complex.

Answer (score 0):

She never had it easy, always working with no breaks.

She never had it be easy, always working with no breaks.

The first is correct, the second sounds foreign.

Example 2:

I was running and had my laces get undone.

I was running and had my laces undo.

Here, I would say that... I was running and my laces undid. 
Or my laces came undone. Or my laces came lose.

About the rest of your question, there are so many examples where we would use have, get and be together that we don't have enough space here on the page.

May you provide some more examples to enable a better understanding of your exact doubt? As I'm still not completely certain in your question.